# Amazon XSD node definitions not found for VariationThemes

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, xsd, amazon-mws

According to the CE.xsd file located here https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/CE.xsd

So we've got the following enumeration values returned for VariationTheme for Consumer Electronics.

"Color", "Size", "Size-Color", "Scent", "Size-Scent", "CustomerPackageType", "ColorName-CustomerPackageType", "SizeName-CustomerPackageType", "SizeName-ColorName-CustomerPackageType", "StyleName-CustomerPackageType", "SizeName-StyleName-CustomerPackageType"

But Only `<Color>` and `<Size>` and `<CustomerPackageType>` exist as nodes. There is no `<Size-Color>` node or `<Size-Scent>` node. So what do they want you to use? Breaking it by "-" doesn't work because there is no `<Scent>` node by itself.

Answer (score 0):

`<Scent>` exists in other XSDs, such as `Beauty.xsd`. Why they put it into `CE.xsd` is beyond me, I guess it is a cut-and-paste error. When using two variants, such as `Size-Color`, you need to specify both `<Size>` and `<Color>`. There is no `<Size-Color>`. Check the documentation for parent/child relations on how to set up variants.

Comment: So sending <Sent> will validate but won't do anything?  I guess I'm supposed to filter the ENUM list by nodes that actually exist in the document then?  These XSDs are a nightmare.

Comment: @SeanClark Sending <Scent> with consumer electronics data will *not* validate. Sending <VariationTheme>Scent</VariationTheme> will validate however, but won't ever actually work.

Comment: Right right. Yes. So would a proper XSD validator catch this? Have you found any validator that works?

Comment: Yes, an XSD validator would catch this, provided you have a full set of XSDs, which is rather hard to obtain.

Comment: Amazon has given me a zip of the XSDs twice now, and neither have XSDs that validate properly. Full of duplicate elements or include URLs that don't resolve.  Did you give up on it, or did you figure that out? I have a 1.5 month old ticket back and forth with Amazon about this already.

Comment: Welcome to the club. If I may cite my own comment: "full set of XSDs, which is rather hard to obtain". I have an outdated set of XSDs I tampered with to remove some non-resolving includes. They now work. Well, kinda. I tried to get release 1.9 to work, but with no success yet.

Comment: I feel like I've been in this club for far too many years.  Amazon told me to use 4.1 and not 1.9.  Even though the actual errors from Amazon reflect 1.9.

I have a 1.5 month old ticket with the the XSD team, and I have people at Amazon helping me with that ticket. Ill keep you updated.